# Issues with else if Java

Tags: java

i am having a little issue trying to create a else if loop in java, what i am trying to do is create a loop the if the number of files in a folder is 1 or less then it does one action if its great than this it goes into another loop

this is my loop so far but does not compile :

```
if (new File(destination).listFiles().length) <=1 {
        return "/GUI/printServerSide.xhtml";
    }else if
         ("txt".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else if ("jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else if ("jpg".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else if ("png".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else if ("gif".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else if ("pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else if ("html".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
        } else {
            return "/GUI/printServerSide.xhtml";
        }


    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There's no loop here.  Also, can you please clean up your question so it doesn't hurt as much to read?

Comment: what error does it showing you ???

Comment: the last ) in the first line is simply in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two errors in the given code snippet, one in the first condition and an extra if...

```
if (new File(destination).listFiles().length <= 1) {
    return "/GUI/printServerSide.xhtml";
}
else if("txt".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else if ("jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else if ("jpg".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else if ("png".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else if ("gif".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else if ("pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else if ("html".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    return "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
}
else {
    return "/GUI/printServerSide.xhtml";
}
```

Comment: @user2065929, if you want to be a professional developer, you really need to be able to handle things like this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
}else if
      ^^
    if ("txt".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
    ^^
```

Comment: Thanks sorry that was a typo, still will not compile however

Comment: @user2065929, What errors are you seeing?

Comment: incompatable types : required boolean found int, else without if, cannot return a value from method whose result type is void and return outside method

Comment: I'm going to guess the method this code is in is returning void and not String

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with your logic you do not need `else-if-else`, just `if` for all the cases would be okay as you are returning the control after every block
Secondly, correct your statement or update your question
`if (new File(destination).listFiles().length) <=1 {`
with this
`if (new File(destination).listFiles().length <=1) {`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
private static final String SUBMITTED_FILE_PREVIEW = "/GUI/submittedFilePreview.xhtml";
private static final String PRINT_SERVER_SIDE = "/GUI/printServerSide.xhtml";

String yourMethod(String destination, String extension) {
    if (new File(destination).listFiles().length <= 1) {
        return PRINT_SERVER_SIDE;
    } else if ("txt".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
            || "jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
            || "jpg".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
            || "png".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
            || "gif".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
            || "pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
            || "html".equalsIgnoreCase(extension))
        return SUBMITTED_FILE_PREVIEW;

    return PRINT_SERVER_SIDE;
}
```